# Баг в String.split()

Tags: java, строки

Мне необходимо разделить строку на несколько отдельных строк, а именно столбец чисел, которые я копирую во входные данные.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = input.nextLine();
        String[] b = a.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
            System.out.println(b[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

При копировании, например

```
23
-6279487 5754764
6919552 -9517926
4259670 864231
-2481110 3721013
-1818946 7978495
```

класс возвращает только число 23.

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public Solution(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (reader.hasNextLine()){
            String a = reader.nextLine();
            String[] b = a.split("\\s+");
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
                System.out.println(b[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: http://www.avl2.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=74:97p9&catid=5:97thingsprogrammer&Itemid=8

Comment: Хорошая статья. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String a = input.nextLine();
```

Этот фрагмент кода считывает одну строку символов (последовательность, заканчивающуюся переносом строки). Вы копируете в консоль несколько строчек. `nextLine` совершенно справедливо берет только первую. Вы разбиваете ее, и в итоговом массиве получаете "23".

Comment: Я понял. А чтобы считать последовательность, которая не заканчивается переносом строки, что надо использовать, я уже по-разному пытался, BufferedReader тоже выдает ответ 23 и все. Я просто пытаюсь решать задачки на http://www.codeabbey.com, просто входные данные по одному числу вписывать долго, вот и пытаюсь модернизировать свой класс. Если что, я новичок, только начал изучать java.

Comment: Все, я сам догнал)

Answer (score 0):

В том, что вы читаете до первого пробела, а нужно считывать, пока в потоке что-то есть.

Comment: Да я понял, надо просто в цикл загнать.
Как всегда сидишь долбишь, долбишь эту клавиатуру, а решение более чем элементарное.